# Update object in the Entity framework that have relations

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to update an whole entity object with relations in database in entity framework , and without success.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var objectToUpdate = DAL.GetProduct(id);
// then I have collection of Comments related to this product.
// and I want to update th whole collection
objectToUpdate.Comments.Clear();
foreach(var newComment in comments){
  objectToUpdate.Comments.Add(newComment);
}
```

What I am getting in database is duplication of all related to my products comments.
Please suggest how to update related Entities properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update a relationship between `objectToUpdate` and a collection of comments which are already existing in the database you need to attach the comments to context before you add them to the `Comments` collection of your `objectToUpdate`. Otherwise EF will create new comment rows in the database:

```
var objectToUpdate = DAL.GetProduct(id);
objectToUpdate.Comments.Clear();
foreach(var newComment in comments)
{
    context.Comments.Attach(newComment);
    objectToUpdate.Comments.Add(newComment);
}
```